# How to build an ArrayList according to the position of each data item

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

Let's say there is a collection of data of type: `{position: i, object}`

How do I build an ArrayList which has the data in the order determined by position but without gaps in the ArrayList?

For example, if the data looks like this:

```
[{position: 3, object3}, {position: 5, object5}, {position: 2, object2}]
```

I would like an ArrayList like this:

```
arrayList[0] == object2;
arrayList[1] == object3;
arrayList[2] == object5;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to sort and/or TreeSet which might be the best choices, you may create a method to insert in order:

```
public static void add( List<YourClass> list, YourClass o ) {
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < list.size(); i++ ) {
        if ( list.get(i).position() > o.position() ) {
            list.add(i, o);
            return;
        }
    }
    list.add(o);
}
```

Full demo program:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
class YourClass {
    private int position;
    private String data;
    public YourClass( int position, String data ) {
        this.position = position;
        this.data = data;
    }
    public int position() {
        return position;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("{position: %d %s}", position, data);
    }
}
class Main {
    public static void main( String ... args ) {
        List<YourClass> list = new ArrayList<>();

        add( list, new YourClass(3, "object 3"));
        add( list, new YourClass(5, "object 5"));
        add( list, new YourClass(2, "object 2"));
        add( list, new YourClass(1, "object 1"));
        System.out.println(list);
    }
    public static void add( List<YourClass> list, YourClass o ) {
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < list.size(); i++ ) {
            if ( list.get(i).position() > o.position() ) {
                list.add(i, o);
                return;
            }
        }
        list.add(o);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
java Main
[{position: 1 object 1}, {position: 2 object 2}, {position: 3 object 3}, {position: 5 object 5}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Sort the collection by position, then iterate over it and add each item to an ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

Great question. Assuming Comparable is implementable, you can use the `compareTo` method (just like in Strings).

So, for example, your custom comparator could look like the following:

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<MyObject> {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
        if (o1.position < o2.position)
            return -1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And to sort your `ArrayList`, you'll need to call:

```
Collections.sort(arrayList, new CustomComparator());
```

Answer (score 1):

You call do this with a `TreeSet` and a `Comparator`:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.TreeSet;

class KeyPair<T> {

    private final int position;
    private final T value;

    public KeyPair(int position, T value) {
        this.position = position;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return position + " => " + value;
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeSet<KeyPair> set = new TreeSet<>((o1, o2) -> o1.getPosition() - o2.getPosition());

        set.add(new KeyPair<>(5, "x"));
        set.add(new KeyPair<>(1, "y"));
        set.add(new KeyPair<>(2, "z"));
        set.add(new KeyPair<>(7, "a"));
        set.add(new KeyPair<>(6, "b"));
        set.add(new KeyPair<>(0, "c"));

        set.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    }

}
```

Output:

```
0 => c
1 => y
2 => z
5 => x
6 => b
7 => a
```

And if you need an `ArrayList` instead of a `TreeSet` you can do this:

```
List<KeyPair> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.addAll(set);
```

The good thing about this approach is that at any point in time you have the collection sorted by `position` if compared with the approach of only sorting in the end.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is really ***position:*** i then first repopulate a new HashMap in the form of {i, object}.

You can then put your hashmap entries inside a TreeMap, this will automaticly sort them. After you just iterate over the TreeMap and put the now sorted objects inside an array.

Example:

```
Map<Integer, Object> map = new TreeMap<>(yourMap);

Object[] sortedArray = new Object[map.size()];
int i = 0;
for(Map.Entry<Integer,Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
  Object value = entry.getValue();
  sortedArray[i]=value;
  i++;
}
```